# Getting JS promise to return a value

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have been looking thru many excellent online examples of getting a Promise to return a value in the .then().  However, there must be something different in my example that is blocking it. I am using nativescript-vue if that makes a difference, but really I think this is a Javascript question.

I have calling vue file:

```
 var person;
 personService.retrievePerson(this.id).then(function(val) {
     console.log("===> received val: " + val); 
    person = val;
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.err(err);
     let message = "Unable to find matching person for id. Please try again.";
     alert(message)
         .then(() => {
             console.log(message);
         });
});
```

Then in my PersonService.js:

```
retrievePerson(id) {
       new Promise(resolve => {

           httpModule.request({
                url: PersonAPI,
                headers: headers,
                method: "GET"
            }).then((response) => {
                // resolve();
                let status = response.statusCode;
                if (status === 200) {
                    let content = JSON.parse(response.content);
                    Person = JSON.parse(response.content);
                    console.log("===> returned [200] PersonService.retrievePerson() response: \"" +  JSON.stringify(Person) + "\"")
                } else if (status === 404) {
                    console.log("===> returned [404] ... returning null ");
                }
                // resolve();
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("===> PersonService.retrievePerson().then() has Person : " + JSON.stringify(Person));
                resolve(Person);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error("retrievePerson() caught error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        });
        }
```

In my console logs I can see the **===> returned [200] PersonService.retrievePerson()** person JSON output, but the calling console "**===> received val**" is not shown.  But I don't know how to get that data back to the calling class to use.

Thank you for your time, I hope you can point out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the promise in your retrievePerson function:

```
retrievePerson(id) {
       return new Promise(resolve => {

           httpModule.request({
                url: PersonAPI,
                headers: headers,
                method: "GET"
            }).then((response) => {
                // resolve();
                let status = response.statusCode;
                if (status === 200) {
                    let content = JSON.parse(response.content);
                    Person = JSON.parse(response.content);
                    console.log("===> returned [200] PersonService.retrievePerson() response: \"" +  JSON.stringify(Person) + "\"")
                } else if (status === 404) {
                    console.log("===> returned [404] ... returning null ");
                }
                // resolve();
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("===> PersonService.retrievePerson().then() has Person : " + JSON.stringify(Person));
                resolve(Person);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error("retrievePerson() caught error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        });
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to await for that Promise to resolve before moving forward in my calling class?

Comment: yes instead of doing `retrievePerson(id).then((person)=>{})` you can await it as such: `let person = retrievePerson(id)` but make sure the function you are calling it in is `async`. you can read up more on Async Await here:  https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to return the promise in your retrievePerson function. However it can also be cleaned up a lot.

You don't need the wrapping promise as you can just return the original one. You shouldn't need the double set of `.then`s as well as you need to make sure you re-throw the error in the `.catch` so your vue file will get a chance to catch the error rather than never resolve as it used to. I'd recommend switching from using `Person` to `const person` in case you run this function twice at the same time there could be a race condition as you change variable asynchronously.

I'd also like to point out one more potential issue: you aren't using the id in your request that I assume based on the console logs is supposed to be used.

```
function retrievePerson(id) {
  return httpModule
    .request({
      url: PersonAPI,
      headers: headers,
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then((response) => {
      let status = response.statusCode;
      if (status === 200) {
        Person = JSON.parse(response.content);
        console.log(
          '===> returned [200] PersonService.retrievePerson() response: "' +
            JSON.stringify(Person) +
            '"'
        );
        return Person;
      } else if (status === 404) {
        console.log('===> returned [404] ... returning null ');
        return null;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('retrievePerson() caught error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the clean code suggestion.  My id was actually used to build the URL but not shown for clarify.